# An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause error

Tags: mysql, database, error-handling

I keep getting an error with this code.

```
SELECT count(first_name)
FROM patients
where gender = 'M' and patient_height > 
    (avg(patient_height))
        having gender = 'F';
```

I want it to show every male who is under the average weight of a female in a database.
An help would be great.

Comment: You will need a sub-query to calculate your average.

Comment: ya but i thought hats what i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, first calculate the average of the female's height on a subquery, then use it on the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
    count(first_name)
FROM
    patients
WHERE
    gender = 'M'
AND
    patient_height > (SELECT avg(patient_height) FROM patients WHERE gender = 'F');
```